# How do I read_until the tokio::net::TcpStream in a future chain?

Tags: asynchronous, tcp, rust, future, rust-tokio

I would like to read data from the `TcpStream` until I encounter a '\0'.
The issue is that `tokio::io::read_until` needs the stream to be `BufRead`.

```
fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<(), Self::Error> {
    match self.listener.poll_accept()? {
        Async::Ready((stream, _addr)) => {
            let task = tokio::io::read_until(stream, 0, vec![0u8; buffer])
                 .map_err(|_| ...)
                 .map(|_| ...);
            tokio::spawn(task);
        }
        Async::NotReady => return Ok(Async::NotReady),
    }
}
```

How can I read data from the `TcpStream` this way?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Please include the **exact** error message you are getting.

Comment: I think my questions are pretty simple for you so it is unnecessary to provide so much data. Today I am a bit in a hurry, but next time I will have more time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the documentation for [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.BufRead.html), you'll see the text:

> If you have something that implements [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Read.html), you can use the [`BufReader` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) to turn it into a `BufRead`.

```
fn example(stream: TcpStream) {
    io::read_until(std::io::BufReader::new(stream), 0, vec![]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But for some reason `read_exact` writes data to the end of the buffer. Actually, I ended up with implementing a custom future that consumes the stream and returns the stream along with the read data as a tuple - just like `write_all`, but for reading.